# Angularjs - watch all directive scope attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a "bar chart" directive in Angular that I want to re-render anytime one of its many scope attributes change.

I am wondering what my options are in terms of watching the scope ...
As the render method is the same independent of what attribute is changed, I would ideally like to watch the whole isolate scope for changes - is that possible? The alternatives I see are either watching a collection of attributes or storing all attributes in a scope.object and watch that object.

```
angular.module('chartPackage')
    .directive('barChart', [function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',

            scope: {
                width: '=',
                height: '=',
                fontSize: '=',
                data: '=',
                colorMap: '=',
                onClick: '=',
                transition: '=',
            },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

             // How to watch all attributes?
             scope.$watch('??????', function(a,b) {
                render();
             }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `watchGroup`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can simply pass a listener without providing a watch expression.

```
scope.$watch(function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue.width);
});
```

Comment: Do be aware that any changes to a model outside of the scope of the `barChart` will trigger the render function if you don't pass the `$watch` a watchExpression. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: ah, so i cannot confine it to the directive's scope?

Comment: No, you need to pass it a watchExpression - otherwise it will simply fire off on every `$digest`. See my answer for the correct way to limit it to a set of passed in properties (tucked away neatly in an object).

Comment: I understand the implications, but the solution you have suggested has already been mentioned by the OP. I was about to edit the post, and add the details regarding its downside. But it seemed that you have explained it already.

Comment: Yes, it has already been mentioned by the OP. In my answer I'm simply saying *"Yes, you are correct in what you're doing"*. Watching the entire suite of `$scopes` and triggering the `render()` function on every `$digest`, is more than likely not what the OP is looking for however. I do apologize if I'm coming off as rude, I just find your answer somewhat misleading in its current state. Please add the details about the downside if you can :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the cleanest option would be to wrap all of the intended attributes in an object, as you mentioned and do the following:

```
angular.module('chartPackage')
  .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.object = {
      width: '',
      height: '',
      fontSize: '',
      data: '',
      colorMap: '',
      onClick: '',
      transition: ''
    };
  })
  .directive('barChart', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',

      scope: {
        object: '='
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        function render () {
          // some render function
        }

        scope.$watch('object', function (a, b) {
          render();
        }, true);

      }
    };
  });

  <bar-chart object="object"></bar-chart>
```

I suppose you could define the object properties inside the template, my own personal preference is to define it in the calling controller context.

The downside of not passing a property (watchExpression) to the `$scope.$watch` function, is the lack of clarity about what properties you are actually watching for changes. If someone were to introduce new properties on the isolate scope of the `barChart`, a 'naked' `$scope.$watch` would pick up on changes in those properties aswell.

Also, `$scope.$watch` with no watchExpression passed to it, would call itself even when changes are made to properties not part of the isolate scope. JsBin here to illustrate it (open up the console and change the `$wat` property in the second input field):

http://jsbin.com/luvotohi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code

```js
function link(scope, element, attrs, Ctrl) {

    scope.$watchCollection(function() {

        var k = 0;

        for (var prop in attrs) {
            if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (!attrs[prop]) ++k
            }
        }
      
        if (k === 1) {
            return attrs
        }

    }, function(value) {
        if (value) {
            // use new value or scope
        }
    }, true);
}
```